# Como consultar 1 CAMPO DEL MISMO nombre de diferentes tablas en MYSQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, tablas

Tengo 5 tablas que tienen los mismos campos:

**ID | Titulo | Comentario | Icono | Solicitud**

Las tablas se llaman:

```
*Contenido1
*Contenido2
*Contenido3
*Contenido4
*Contenido5
```

Lo que necesito es consultar los registros de la columna "**Solicitud**" (E icono) de las 5 tablas.

Es decir necesito algo así como una sintaxis que me de "TODOS LOS DATOS" (Para yo poder pintarlos por pantalla de mayor a menor y con un límite de  por ejemplo 8 -- Nota; esto último creo se soluciona simple con un ORDER BY)

¿Alguna idea con la sintaxis? (Estoy trabajando en PHPMYADMIN).

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_union.asp

Comment: Me contesto a mi mismo por si alguien esta en la misma situación; Se utiliza UNION (Yo lo resolví con UNION SELECT)

Comment: Fantástico! si tan solo alguien te lo hubiera dicho

Comment: Yussef no vi tu respuesta, te agradezco de igual forma.

Answer (score 0):

Si es que entiendo tu pregunta, creo que con JOIN's y un ALIAS ya te lo solucionaría no?

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-select-data-from-multiple-tables/

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).